# SQL Join/Nested Query

Tags: sql, join

Query is: Display country codes and names which have more than 2 official languages

My answer is:

```
select 
    c.country_name, 
    cl.countrycode
from 
    country c, 
    countrylanguage cl
where 
    c.code=cl.countrycode and c.code IN

    ( select code 

        from countrylanguage
        where cl.isOfficial='T'
        group by cl.countrycode
        having count(cl.isOfficial)>2
    );
```

The problem is that if any country has 3 official languages thats is greater than 2, that many times identical output is displayed like
ZWE zimbabwe
ZWE zimbabwe
ZWE zimbabwe

But i need only one
There are two tables given as follows

```
CountryLanguage (CountryCode, Language ,IsOfficial ,Percentage)

Country (Code ,country_Name)
```

This tables has a few more attributes but we don't require them right now to answer this query.

Comment: what type of database are you working in?  MySql, Oracle, SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be exlicitly `JOIN`ing your tables. That means `JOIN` clauses. Your `FROM` clause should **never** **ever** have more than one table in it.

Next, name your columns consistently. Are you using underscores in column names or no?

Since each country only has a single code (I'm assuming), you can just `GROUP BY` in your main query - no need for a subquery at all.

```
SELECT
    C.country_name,
    CL.country_code
FROM
    Country C
INNER JOIN CountryLanguage CL ON CL.country_code = C.code
GROUP BY
    C.country_name,
    CL.country_code
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: Did I miss where he specified his database type?  Are you assuming MySQL?

Comment: I'm assuming just about any major SQL dialect that exists.

Comment: putting comma separated tables in the from clause is essentially the same as using joins, at least for SQL Server

Comment: Exactly, same for Oracle.  You say never ever, but that's simply not true.

Comment: No @ElenaDBA, it's not. It most definitely, very much, is not, and it's a horrible habit to get into.

Comment: it is more opinion based. they are exactly the same performance wise

Comment: I'd be curious to see if there are actually any performance differences or other real issues, because I've worked in an Oracle environment for 8 years and never once seen "inner join" explicitly stated.

Comment: No, it's really not. There are some set-based operations that cannot be performed with the 20-year old "old style" joins or might return different results based simply on how the SQL engine decides to parse the statement. Also, Oracle supports `JOIN` clauses and has since 2001. Time to catch up with the times.

Comment: Okay, this is what i have now        select c.country_name, cl.countrycode
from country c, countrylanguage cl
where c.code=cl.countrycode and cl.countrycode IN  (select countrycode
                                            from countrylanguage
                                   where isOfficial='T'
                                   group by countrycode
                                   having count(isOfficial)>2);

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for this.  Here's one using `exists`:

```
select code, country_name
from country c
where exists (
    select 1
    from countrylanguage cl 
    where c.code = cl.countrycode
    group by cl.code
    having count(*) > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL, valid for all DB:

```
select
    country.countrycode,
    country.country_name
from
    country
    join countrylanguage on country.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
where
    countrylanguage.isofficial = 'T'
group by
    country.countrycode,
    country.country_name
having
    count(*) > 2
```